# Saturating colors in HSV color space

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on a project that allows color-blind computer users to differentiate between colors (currently focusing on red-green color blindness).

Although I have programmed algorithms for the LAB color space (intensifying A and B coordinates to pure red and pure green) and RGB (contrast scaling), how should I go about separating these colors in the HSV color space? What would be the ideal approach- searching for an ideal multiplier value for the Saturation component in the image, or improving the image through both H and S values. Suggestions and inputs are welcome. I am using MATLAB.

Comment: Please tell me a little about color-blindness. What colors are you trying to change (to let color-blind people become able to see) and how do you want to make this happen? (By changing the color or the saturation o what)?